# xrandr batmach error

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I am trying to add this resolution on connected device : DVI-I-0

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.96*   59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x277) 172.800MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2040 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.08KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1118           clock  60.00Hz
```

xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1920x1080_60.00

but this error occurs :

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
```

Any solution? please help me

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to create the new mode first:- `cvt 1920 1080 60` and then  `xrandr --newmode <content after Modeline from cvt output>`

Comment: Can you tell me which graphic card and driver are you using. Meanwhile try adding this in monitor section of xorg.conf `HorizSync  30-82`
`VertRefresh  56-76` and then restart.